# filter json and write output to csv

Tags: python, json, csv

How do I filter out a particular key-value pair of a JSON file and write the rest to CSV?

i.e. filter out the `headerName` key and write `URL, Domain, Pages` to a CSV file:

```
[{"URL": "http://help.abc.com/", "headerName": Null, "Domain": "www.abc.com", "Pages": "27"},
 {"URL": "https://support.bcd.com/", "headerName": Null, "Domain": "www.bcd.com", "Pages": "15"}]
```

This would produce:

```
"http://help.abc.com/", "www.abc.com", "27"
"https://support.bcd.com/", "www.bcd.com", "15"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`csv.DictWriter()` instance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to handle writing those to a file, give it `URL`, `Domain` and `Pages` as field names and set the `extrasaction` argument to `'ignore'`:

> The *fieldnames* parameter is a sequence of keys that identify the order in which values in the dictionary passed to the `writerow()` method are written to the *csvfile*.
>
> [...]
>
> If the dictionary passed to the `writerow()` method contains a key not found in *fieldnames*, the optional *extrasaction* parameter indicates what action to take. If it is set to `'raise'` a `ValueError` is raised. If it is set to `'ignore'`, extra values in the dictionary are ignored.

You can then simply pass your list of dictionaries straight to the `writer.writerows()` method:

```
import csv
import json

with open(outputfilename, 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile,
        fieldnames=('URL', 'Domain', 'Pages'),
        extrasaction='ignore')

    your_json_list = json.loads(your_json_string)
    writer.writerows(your_json_list)
```